# css background image position fixed not working as expected

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html5boilerplate

I am a newbie in UI development, started building my first web application recently and chose html5-boilerplate framework. I have developed my first html page and hosted   it under http://www.techtrek.guru domain.

I am struck with few issue:

1. I want the hero image to be fixed and want the text to scroll when scrolling the page. Currently the hero image also scrolls up when I scroll the web page.

   I added the `position:fixed` property to the `.hero` class but it does not work as expected. In addition I also tried adding the `z-index` property to `-10` which also is not working.

Could you please help me understand where I am going wrong?

Comment: So you want the image to be covered by the "Learning technology..." section when scrolling down?

Comment: I want the ""Learning technology..." section to scroll up when I scroll the page but want the background image to stay fixed.

Comment: Done, check my answer. Also, you may want to add a non-empty `<title>` to your page so it validates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

to the `.hero` class. [Reference for background-attachment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-attachment).

Comment: Thanks. this works but partially. Because when I resize the width of the screen the image also resizes till a point and then stay fixed.

Comment: @Pradeep: That should be asked in a different question; after all, the image didn't resize in the original version either and you didn't mention this in the question statement.

Comment: Ok. I will ask another question on that. This helped me. Thanks

Comment: @Pradeep: Glad to help; make sure to accept it as the answer then by clicking the outlined checkmark.